# Error: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to E

Tags: java

Completely stuck on this error. Here's the class the error is coming from.

```
 /** An array-based Stack. */    
 public class ArrayStack<E> implements Stack {

 /** Array of items in this Stack. */  
 private E[] data; 

 /** Number of items currently in this Stack. */  
 private int size;

 /** The Stack is initially empty. */  
 public ArrayStack() {  
 data = (E[])(new Object[1]); // This causes a compiler warning  
 size = 0;  
 }

 public boolean isEmpty() {  
 return size == 0;  
 }

 public Object pop() {  
 if (isEmpty()) {  
 throw new EmptyStructureException();   
 }  
 size--;  
 return data[size];  
 }  

 public Object peek() {  
 if (isEmpty()) {  
 throw new EmptyStructureException();  
 }  
 return data[size - 1];  
 }  

 /** Return true if data is full. */  
 protected boolean isFull() {  
 return size == data.length;  
 }  

 public void push(Object target) {  
 if (isFull()) {  
 stretch();  
 }  
 data[size] = target;  
 size++;  
 }  

 /** Double the length of data. */  
 protected void stretch() {  
 E[] newData = (E[])(new Object[data.length * 2]); // Warning  
 for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
 newData[i] = data[i];  
 }  
 data = newData;  
 }  
}
```

Here's the Stack class just in case it's needed:

```
 /** A last-in, first-out stack. */  
 public interface Stack<E> {  

 /** Return true if this Stack is empty. */  
 public boolean isEmpty();  

 /**  
 * Return the top item on this Stack, but do not modify the Stack.  
 * @throws EmptyStructureException if this Stack is empty.  
 */  
 public E peek();  

 /**  
 * Remove and return the top item on this Stack.  
 * @throws EmptyStructureException if this Stack is empty.  
 */  
 public E pop();  

 /** Add target to the top of the Stack. */  
 public void push(E target);  

 }
```

The error is in regards to the line  `data[size] = target;` in the ArrayStack class, in the push(Object target) method.

Comment: A few thoughts: 1) `ArrayStack<E> implements Stack<E>` instead of simply implementing `Stack`. 2) Then you can get rid of all the `Object` mentions. Also, `new E[data.length * 2]` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/**
 * An array-based Stack.
 */
public class ArrayStack<E> implements Stack<E> {

/**
 * Array of items in this Stack.
 */
private E[] data;

/**
 * Number of items currently in this Stack.
 */
private int size;

/**
 * The Stack is initially empty.
 */
public ArrayStack() {
    data = (E[]) (new Object[1]); // This causes a compiler warning  
    size = 0;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}

public E pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    size--;
    return data[size];
}

public E peek() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    return data[size - 1];
}

/**
 * Return true if data is full.
 */
protected boolean isFull() {
    return size == data.length;
}

public void push(E target) {
    if (isFull()) {
        stretch();
    }
    data[size] = target;
    size++;
}

/**
 * Double the length of data.
 */
protected void stretch() {
    E[] newData = (E[]) (new Object[data.length * 2]); // Warning  
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        newData[i] = data[i];
    }
    data = newData;
}
}
```

Comment: This worked! The kicker was adding <E> after Stack in the first line on top of everything else.

Answer (score 3):

```
data[size] = target;
```

1) Here `data` refers to `E array` and `target` refers to `Object`.
Generics brings type safety. So you cannot cannot convert from Object to E.

2)  `public class ArrayStack<E> implements Stack {`

is not correct because you don't provide the parameterized type for the interface you are implementing. 
Writing  `public class ArrayStack<E> implements Stack<E> {` would be safer and will force you to implement the `Stack` methods by respecting the parameterized  type used in the `Stack` methods.
For example :  `public void push(E target);`

3) To be conform to declared parameterized type in `ArrayStack` you should should use the parameterized type in your method instead of `Object`.

so you should replace

```
 public void push(Object target) {
```

by

```
 public void push(E target) {
```

And you should do the same thing in all methods you declare that manipulate as declared type `Object`  instead of `E`. For example :

```
 public Object peek()
```

and

```
 public Object pop() {
```

Answer (score 1):

Target and data are not of the same type. You can use `E` wherhever you need a type. This makes your code more type safe.

Change the push method to:

```
public void push(E target) {  
 if (isFull()) {  
   stretch();  
 }  
 data[size] = target;  
 size++;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your data array is of type E:

```
private E[] data;
```

You need to modify:

```
 public void push(Object target) {
```

to have parameter type E.

E can be String, Integer etc determined at runtime. Object is not equivalent to the runtime type.

Comment: Actually, I think that `Object` _is_ the runtime type, it's just that allowing the assignment he was making is not type safe, and could lead to problems, hence generics failed at compile time.